# Accents "é, è ... etc" not displayed properly

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am using PDO to execute queries in PHP. The problem is when adding characters with accent ("é", "è", "ô" and etc...) via phpMyAdmin and retrieving it in PHP, it display strange characters. When the accent is added via a query, it is stored as a strange character ('é' would be 'Ã©') but it is displayed properly.

The charset I use in MySQL is `utf8_general_ci`. My PHP charset is set to UTF-8 (without BOM). When I execute a query like:

```
SELECT ... WHERE DataName LIKE '%é%' ...
```

it doesn't work if the data has been added via phpMyAdmin and is not set to 'Ã©'.

I'd like to know how to make this work even when we add data via phpMyAdmin and displays as "é" in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: What encoding your webserver is returning in his HTTP headers ?

Comment: Also, did you try playing around with `utf8_decode()` / `utf_encode()` ?

Comment: I don't know the encoding in the header, but my html page is set to UTF-8 (in the meta). But even when I do queries (in my php script, so on server and no header sent to the user) the problem is the same. I have to compare 'É' to 'E' to make it works. So I don't think the problem is related to headers (or only related to the headers).

Comment: utf8_general_ci is not a charset, is a collation. A collation tells the database how to order data. In some collations the order is 1,10,2,3,30,4,5..  in other can be 1,2,3,4,5,6,..10,...20.    utf8_general_ci seems the "utf-8 aware" collation, so will order text correctly acording some abstract way to order text. You probably sould set the connection to utf-8 if you saved the data in a conexion set to utf-8.

Comment: I also added "charset=UTF-8" in the connection string, but it doesn't fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you establish UTF8 for all communications between PDO and MySQL

```
$handle = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", 
    'username', 'password',  
    array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

Comment: it show me an error : Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND'. I already have looked into this and the solution was to set ';charset=UTF-8' after the 'dbname'. But even the charset=UTF-8 didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My Batch file initialized the table inputing words with accent, but my phpmyadmin shown a strange figure. But when I changed it in the phpmyadmin it was saved correctly and when I exported to a batch was also correct (the same batch that loaded the strange figure)
I fond the problem when I used the Jedit editor instead Notepad. For some reason the Notepad convert the strange figure to accent.
Knowing that problem the solution was easy:

1- Created by Database using latin1:

DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `mydb`;

CREATE DATABASE `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

2- Checked the batch files to input the correct accent

3- Used the regular declaration on html header: META charset="utf-8"